# Python tensorflow: asyncio or threading

Tags: python, tensorflow, websocket, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am implementing a server for recognizing objects in photos using tensorflow-gpu in "semi-real" time.  It will listen for new photos on a websocket connection, then enqueue it into a list for the detector run when it is free.  Would it be simpler to use asyncio or threading to handle the websocket listener and the recognition queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I used `asyncio` to handle the websocket connection, enqueuing incoming images to a queue.  I used `threading` which had a thread to read the image into RAM, extracted some metadata, and queued it for the object detector. The detector, running in another thread, tagged the images and queued the tags in the database handler (yet another thread).

Comment: The object detector when using tensorflow-gpu is still blocking. And due to Python GIL, the threads are not truely parallel. Doesnt' that end up blocking your entire program?

Comment: Good point.  It was performant enough for my needs, less than 1s per image (Ryzen 2950X, RTX2080 GPU, and a retrained resnet-v2 from the pre-trained tensorflow-models).  I was considering switching to the tensorflow pipelines for reading the images if it was too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in threading/asyncio but maybe it would be easier to spawn an instance of Kafka and have a piece of code that would listen to a Kafka topic? To this topic you would push images or paths to images if you already store them locally. Moreover, using `consumer-groups` you would get a load balancing like thing for free as it is a part of Kafka.